# Deleting specific string lines of items in array Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I have an array of 10 items containing of a several lines string like

```
one string
two string
some string
any string
```

I want to delete lines containing words some and two. I made code like that:

```
search_text_domain = %r{some|two}
    groups_data.each do |line|
        line.each_line do |num|
        domain_users_name << (num) unless num =~ search_text_domain
        end
    end
```

It works fine but it puts all lines to one big array like 
`domain_users_name = ["one string", "any string", "big string", "another_s....]` and I want tu put it in array of arrays like

```
domain_users_name = [["one string", "any string"], ["big string", ""another_s...."], [........
```

I need version that permanently modify groups_data array. Any ideas?

Comment: And if one string of the subarray contains "some" or "two", should the whole subarray be discarded or should just that one string?

Comment: Just that one string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input = ["one string\ntwo string\nsome string\nany string",
         "one string\ntwo string\nsome string\nany string"]


input.map { |a| a.split("\n").reject { |e| e =~ %r{some|two} } }

# or
# input.map { |a| a.each_line.map(&:strip).reject { |e| e =~ %r{some|two} } }

# or (smiley-powered version, see the method’s tail)
# input.map { |a| a.each_line.map(&:strip).reject(&%r{some|two}.method(:=~)) }

#⇒ [["one string", "any string"], ["one string", "any string"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to delete a group if one of the group elements matches the filter regexp?

```
groups = [['some', 'word'], ['other', 'word'], ['unrelated', 'list', 'of', 'things']]

filter = %r{word|some}
filtered = groups.delete_if do |group|
  group.any? do |word|
    word =~ filter
  end
end

p filtered
```

Does this do what you want?

Comment: Items of original array looks like
`array = ["one string\nsecond string", "other string\nother other string]` - there are new lines. And I want to delete lines containing of specific words and after deleting e.g. line with wird secon get array = ["one string", "other string\nother other string"]